# Non-recursive make: include makefile segment in a loop

Tags: c++, makefile, gnu-make

I have a non recursive makefile which defines helper functions which can be used to build libraries etc

```
define make-library
    # build lib from *.cpp in current dir...
endef
```

Each library/binary is defined in a separate makefile segment called `module.mk` which calls these helper functions

```
$(eval $(call make-library, my_lib))
```

The makefile searches the source tree for makefile segments, and includes them

```
modules := $(shell find . -name module.mk | xargs echo)
include $(modules)
```

#### Problem:

I define a default set of `CPPFLAGS` at the top of the makefile:

```
CPPFLAGS += -m64 -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wno-system-headers
```

They are selectively updated depending on build variant etc:

```
ifeq "$(BUILD)" "debug"
    CPPFLAGS += $(DEBUG_FLAGS)
endif
```

they are used in each target where required:

```
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp
    @$(CXX) $(CPPFLAGS) -I$(BASE_DIR) -I. -o $@ -c $(filter %.cpp,$^)
```

The problem I have is that sometimes I want to override `CPPFLAGS` in a module:

```
CPPFLAGS += -Wno-unused-but-set-variable
$(eval $(call make-library, my_lib))
```

However, this updates the **global** `CPPFLAGS`, so every module gets the updated flags.

#### Solution:

My idea is to iterate over `$(modules)`, and before including each one, reset `CPPFLAGS` to a default set. Any changes in the current module will be reset for the next.

Something along the lines of:

```
$(foreach module,$(modules),$(eval \
    CPPFLAGS := DEFAULT_CPPFLAGS \
    include $module))
```

#### Question:

The above syntax is incorrect, but should hopefully illustrate what I'm trying to achieve - any ideas on how best to do what I've described?

#### Alternative:

Alternately, perhaps each `module.mk` could define a `LOCAL_FLAGS` variable which could be passed to the `make-library` call?

```
LOCAL_FLAGS := -Wno-unused-but-set-variable
$(eval $(call make-library, my_lib, $(LOCAL_FLAGS)))
```

Comment: Try passing the extra parameters manually with if…else…?

Comment: There's no reason to pipe the output of `find` to `xargs echo`.

Comment: I don't that will work: the reason  is that CPPFLAGS will still be defined by the last iteration of the foreach and not really "in between" each module.  Maybe use target specific variables?

Comment: How do you use `CPPFLAGS` in the various `module.mk` files? Do you expect them to have the correct values at target recipe runtime or just at makefile parse time? (i.e. Are they used in recipe lines or added to other simply expanded (:=) variables during the parse phase?)

Comment: @EtanReisner I've updated the question with additional information around the use of `CPPFLAGS`

Comment: See my answer. The only way I'm aware of to have "local" variables is to use local names or store them on targets, etc. Like you responded to @Isaiah the value you get at recipe time is the last value assigned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have per-makefile variables if they are used at recipe time. Recipes execute after all assignments/etc. have been done.

If you use file-local variables or force the global variables expansion at parse time you can do this though.

You can save, set, use and reset the values in each `module.mk` file.

```
$ cat foo/module.mk
oCPPFLAGS:=$(CPPFLAGS)
CPPFLAGS+=something local

target: CPPFLAGS:=$(CPPFLAGS)
target:
        some_cmd $(CPPFLAGS)

FOO:=$(oFOO)
```

Or, more like your original attempt, you can force eval them back to some default value during the loop.

```
$ cat Makefile
$(foreach module,$(modules),$(eval CPPFLAGS := DEFAULT_CPPFLAGS)$(eval include $(module)))
$(eval CPPFLAGS := DEFAULT_CPPFLAGS)

$ cat foo/module.mk
target: CPPFLAGS:=$(CPPFLAGS)
target:
        some_cmd $(CPPFLAGS)
```

But the important thing here is the variables are expanded/used at parse time. They cannot be used at recipe time unless they are saved in some other variable (like the target-specific ones in the examples above).

Comment: Thanks for your response! One thing which I suspect won't work is the general `$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.cpp` rule, since this is not target specific. Is it possible to have a `.o: .cpp` rule *per target*? Doesn't seem right?

Comment: That rule/recipe isn't but target-specific variables apply to all their prerequisites. "There is one more special feature of target-specific variables: when you define a target-specific variable that variable value is also in effect for all prerequisites of this target, and all their prerequisites, etc. (unless those prerequisites override that variable with their own target-specific variable value)." From http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Target_002dspecific

Comment: target specific variables worked perfectly - thanks!

Comment: Uhhm, your first example is missing a `target:` for the recipe.

Answer (score 1):

In my   [**prorab**](https://github.com/cppfw/prorab) build system I pass arguments to compiler from `this_*` variables instead of global `CFLAGS`, though `CFLAGS` is passed to compiler also.
Then, after I defined the build rules I can clear all the `this_*` variables like this:

```
$(foreach var,$(filter this_%,$(.VARIABLES)),$(eval $(var) := ))
```

And I created a definition for this

```
prorab-clear-this-vars = $(foreach var,$(filter this_%,$(.VARIABLES)),$(eval $(var) := ))
```

And it can be used like this

```
$(eval $(prorab-clear-this-vars))
```