# Expanding make variables at pattern definition time

Tags: gnu-make

Here's a trivialised example of a much more complex build system that I'm working on.

```
T := 1

$T/foo.o: $T/foo.c
  touch $T/foo.o  # yes, I know I can use $@, this is an example

T := 2

$T/foo.o: $T/foo.c
  touch $T/foo.o  # yes, I know I can use $@, this is an example
```

(Both patterns are defined in an include file, so they have to be the same text.)

This doesn't work. While the patterns themselves are created properly, with rules called `1/foo.o: 1/foo.c` and `2/foo.o: 2/foo.c`, the recipes themselves don't get `$T` expanded until they're actually executed; at which point, of course, `$T` has the value 2, even in the first recipe.

The only way I know to force the variables to be expanded at the point where the recipe is defined is to put the entire pattern inside a multiline variable and then expand it with `$(eval)`... which is grotesque.

I realise the answer here is probably going to be *no*, but are there any other ways to force `$T` to be expanded inline in the above recipes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Non-recursive make: include makefile segment in a loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27911944/non-recursive-make-include-makefile-segment-in-a-loop)

Comment: You can use target-specific variables to "capture" variables at parse time to do this sort of thing. See the question I linked.

Comment: Target-specific variables are horribly dangerous; they propagate down through the dependency tree, which means that if the same dependency is visible via more than one top level rule, and those top-level rules use different target-specific variables, then which definition the dependency sees depends _on the order of execution of your makefile_. Which is undefined.

Comment: This is actually take #2 at a build system which crashed and burned because of aforesaid target-specific variable problem. Later versions of make fix this with the addition of `private` target-specific variables, but they're not widespread enough to help me yet.

Comment: Newer versions of make support the [`private`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Suppressing-Inheritance) variable modifier to avoid that problem. But yes, without that they can be problematic when you don't want that behavior (and ideal when you do).

Comment: See, for example: https://ciaranm.wordpress.com/2008/07/22/gnu-make-target-specific-variables-are-dumb/

Comment: Argh! Multithreaded race condition in comments!

Comment: Yeah, other than direct eval and target-specific variables I'm not sure you have any other options. (At least that aren't horrible hacks like target-specific env files that you write out at parse time and read at recipe time.)

Comment: First, no, there is no way to force some variables in a recipe to expand while the makefile is being parsed.  Second, it's not true that the order of execution of a makefile is undefined, although running jobs in parallel can make the order non-deterministic.  Third, you shouldn't use target-specific variables in situations where that might be a problem (which seems to make it OK for your use-case) or else use the `private` keyword to avoid the recursion.  Fourth you have one other option, which I doubt you'll like any better: constructed variable names.

Comment: Lastly, this model of re-using the same variable name over and over is simply a poor method of writing makefiles and should be avoided.

Comment: I just came up with constructed variable names as an idea a few minutes ago (in the shower). I also thought of switching which is used based on support for `private`. I don't have time to write something up now but I'll try to do that a bit later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see you have three choices.

1. Target-specific variables
2. Parse-time rule definition (`eval`, etc.).
3. Constructed variable names.

#### Using Target-Specific Variables

```
T := 1

$T/foo.o: T:=$T
$T/foo.o: $T/foo.c
  touch $T/foo.o  # yes, I know I can use $@, this is an example

T := 2

$T/foo.o: T:=$T
$T/foo.o: $T/foo.c
  touch $T/foo.o  # yes, I know I can use $@, this is an example
```

As discussed [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30335961/expanding-make-variables-at-pattern-definition-time?noredirect=1#comment48766532_30335961) on the question target-specific variables are visible to all the prerequisites of the target in question (unless using the GNU make 3.82 `private` feature) which may not always be what you want.

#### Using Parse-time Rule Definitions

```
define foorule
$T/foo.o: $T/foo.c
        touch $T/foo.o  # yes, I know I can use $$$$@, this is an example
endef

T := 1
$(eval $(foorule))

T := 2
$(eval $(foorule))
```

But (as mentioned in the question) this isn't exactly pretty and requires occasionally careful negotiation of expansions (for things that want to be expanded at recipe time as compared to those things that don't).

#### Using Constructed Variable Names

```
T := 1

T$(T) := $T
$T/foo.o: $T/foo.c
  touch $(T1)/foo.o  # yes, I know I can use $@, this is an example

T := 2

T$T := $T
$T/foo.o: $T/foo.c
  touch $(T2)/foo.o  # yes, I know I can use $@, this is an example
```

This has the same non-propagating effect as using `private` at the cost of having the value "leak" to **every** target instead (under the constructed name).

You could wrap this in a define to remove the manual construction and use of the variable (though how that benefits you over just using the define itself is unclear in most cases).

It would be possible to combine the private and define or constructed makefile uses for make version compatibility. However support for `private` is not indicated in `.FEATURES` so one would need to use `oneshell` as a proxy as it was also introduced in make 3.82.

Comment: I'm actually going for option 2, except every time I do `$(eval $(var))` I die a little inside... Thanks for the comprehensive answer; that's what I thought, but it's nice to have it confirmed. (I've passed the point of hating make. Now it just makes me so, so sad.)

Comment: Incidentally: `T($T) := $T`. Is this special syntax or a typo? Right now I'm doing this with `$(eval T$T := $T)`, but it's a pain.

Comment: Typo. I meant `T$(T)` but `T$T` would have worked too.

Comment: So it does. I wonder why I thought I need `eval`? *shrug* Anyway, ta.

Comment: If this is a make generator I'd probably go for feature detection and preferring `private` so that eventually the define version can go away. But that's a fair bit of overhead (and possibly two different recipe generation models) so might not be worth it.